# Android in-app billing tiers

Tags: android, localization, in-app-billing, currency

An app for a US client sells a subscription for $1.99/month through in-app billing. When I test the app from the Netherlands, the local price is reported to be €2.11. Two questions:

1. Where can I find the price tier information per country? The amount seems incorrect because right now the EUR is worth more than the USD, not less.
2. It is not formatting the price correctly. Is this a bug? It should display € 2,11 in NL and 2,11 € in FR but it's not doing this. It's only converting the amount and not localizing the way the currency is displayed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the conversion in your google play developer account for the app. Check the in app product you created and you'll be ablt to either auto convert or override the prices.

Here's how it typically looks

[image]

Comment: I will mark this as correct, though I'd still appreciate a response from someone about the 2nd part of my question. Thanks!